# Question about self adjointness

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a Hilbert space and $T:A\to A$ be linear and bounded. Is it in general true that 
$$T^*T \qquad \text{and}\qquad T+T^*$$

will both be self-adjoint? My intuition tells me the first one will be but I have been having some trouble proving it..

Answer (score 1):

In any functional analysis text, you should be able to find quick proofs of the following: 
$$
(S + T)^* = S^* + T^*\\
(ST)^* = T^*S^*\\
(T^*)^* = T
$$
putting these three statements together, it's easy to see that both $T+T^*$ and $T^*T$ will generally be self-adjoint.

Answer (score 0):

These are easy to show directly:
$$
\langle T^* T x,y\rangle = \langle T x,T y\rangle = \langle x,T^*T y\rangle
$$
and
$$
\langle (T + T^*) x,y\rangle = \langle T x,y\rangle + \langle T^* x,y\rangle
= \langle x,T^* y\rangle + \langle x,T y\rangle
= \langle x,(T^* + T) y\rangle.
$$